# Can't find "Enable Download" in Power Query

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

I am connecting to PostgreSQL through MS Excel's Power Query.

I summarize the table in a Pivot Table (SQL would be roughly SELECT category, SUM(sales) GROUP BY category)

I only need the resulting pivot table, or sales grouped by category.

However, I end up with a 60mb file (or other big size, depending on the Postgre table size)

I assumed that PowerQuery is downloading the source data.

I found this:
[http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2013/9/7/power-query-datashould-it-be-loaded-to-the-worksheet.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yBiYJ.jpg)
[][2]

However, I cannot find this Query Settings pane anywhere, my layout looks completely different.

Could you tell me how to disable downloading of source data from a database?

Answer (score 1):

I think the settings you want to get to are these:

[image]

One way to get to these settings is by:

1. Click on the 'Data' tab in Excel.
2. Click 'Show Queries' in the ribbon below the 'Data' tab.
   (At this point you should see your queries on the right side of your screen.)
3. Right-click the query for which you want to adjust settings.
4. Select 'Load To...'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however, this is not what I am looking for - I already tried all those settings, including only creating a connection without adding to data model, and this time I ended up with a 28mb file. Question remains: is this size resulting from the fact, that Excel is downloading and saving some source data, meaning the actual rows that it then calculates? How to turn it off, and tell Excel to only do calculations in RAM, and save only those few kilobates that compose the pivot table report?